# Unit testing Controller action decorated with customattribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

Controller action has been decorated with custom implementation of   System.Security.Permissions.CodeAccessSecurityAttribute as shown below.How can inject dependency for the attribute while unit testing controller action method. Testing has become more difficult by direct used of ConfigurationManager Class inside it. The code for security attribute has been provided by client and we are not suppose to change it. Is there any other way to inject dependency so that I can unit test the controller method without changing the custom CodeAccessSecurityAttribute.

```
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class CustomSecurityAttribute : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    public CustomSecurityAttribute(SecurityAction action)
        : base(action)
    {
    }

    public string Roles { get; set; }

    public override IPermission CreatePermission()
    {
            ConfigurationManager.GetSection("procedureList") as NameValueCollection
            result = new PrincipalPermission(null, roles[0]);


        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but a tip. This kind of thing is a little hard do mock. Matt Honeycutt created specsfor framework to help mock hard things like that, you can take a look, maybe it could help you: http://specsfor.com/

Comment: Can you please show the code under test, i.e what you trying to test here? If we can see there might be way to simplify the code a bit.